# Equations are distorted in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, equation-editor

I am trying to create some math equations in Microsoft PowerPoint but they are distorted both on the desktop and the web app:

> [image]

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what the problem is and how I can resolve it. I am using Windows 10 and PowerPoint version 2208.

**P.S.** Following [this Tweet](https://twitter.com/fsfarimani/status/1641732769406410753?s=20), by the Microsoft Support team over there. They asked me to run the software in safe mode using:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\powerpnt.exe" /safe
```

now if I open the old .pptx file in safe mode, the equations are still distorted. But I create a new .pptx and create new equations over there, they are fine!

Comment: Please also add how they are supposed to look like.

Comment: @harrymc well, I don't have a good PowerPoint example at the moment, but the fraction's numerator and denominator should be equally spaced and the "Nf" must be right between the parenthesis. the fraction's line should be vertically aligned with the negative sign...

Comment: Is you PowerPoint file generated by a program?

Comment: @harrymc no. I generated the slides in the PowerPoint.

Comment: Did you check your fonts?

Comment: Did you check if any of the text is in Superscript, Subscript or Offset?